# jquery button scroll on click

Tags: jquery, events, scroll, click

I am making buttons, when hovered shows me border on specifiec items, which suits it's category. But I meet some problems, when there are more images, they are not visible on page, I have to scroll down.

My code right now looks

```
$(".cat1-button").hover(function () {
    $(".cat1").css("border", "4px solid #4f7b37");
});
$(".cat1-button").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".cat1").css("border", "4px solid #e7e7e7");
});
```

And I have to add a click state, which will be doing nothing more than "scroll to top of an button". How to do it ?
I will try to explain this more:

I have buttons one under another, and when clicked I want to scroll to top of each -> so the button will be on my top screen. Like anchoring using a href="#cat1-button".

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Can you give us a demo which can show what is the exact issue is?

Comment: it's not an issue, I need to add this feature (on click scroll to top of each button). 

I have two column page, where on left side are buttons, and on right are images that shows me a specifiec border when hovered. But the most bottom buttons and most button images are visible only when i scroll down page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** Check this DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/g9cg0jn3/2/

Add below scripts for all buttons click and now you are good to go, the page will scroll to each button that is clicked.

#### JQUERY

```
$("li[class*='-button']").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 3 }, 500);
});
```

Comment: My buttons looks like:

<ul>
                            <li class="cat1-button">Cat 1</li>
                            <li class="cat2-button">Cat 2</li>
                        </ul>

and if I am right, it will scroll me to top of my page. And that's not what I am looking for, I want to scroll to each (clicked) button.

Comment: Can you post your sample HTML, button + image? So we can write detail for you.

Comment: Thank You, love the on:hover scroll also. That's what I needed. THANK YOU A LOT :-)

Answer (score 1):

This code may work for you. What this basically does is, it finds the element #cat1-button and scrolls as the position of that element from top of the window. You can arrange this according to your needs.

```
$(window).scrollTop($('#cat1-button').offset().top);
```

[You can find more on scrollTop() here](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Comment: what about more simple way to just add click function to code to scroll itself to top ?
so the button clicked will have #top to itself.

In a href I would use anchors, but I don't know how to do it using jquery.

I don't want to rearrange anything, or change their positions, what I need is just simple scroll scrollbars to make clicked button be on the top of browser's window.

Comment: Just change '#cat1-button' with the id or class of the whatever object you want and you have what you want.. If you want it to take the clicked element automatically just use  $(window).scrollTop($(this).offset().top);